# Examples of Scientific Data representation through D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am Data Vis Research student. I am working on the report on D3.js on various data attributes/types. I have had a hard time, finding any good example of scientific Data representation through D3.js. I have been through few of the visualization based on gravity, momentum, force directed graph. But, I am unable to find any example that can show scientific experimental results like Chemical fusion, Einstein law in action, growth or depletion of cells in some body, Black hole functioning etc... wherein if we change values of data variables, it shows the difference in visualization.

I hope its not too much from D3.js

Comment: This is probably better addressed to the d3 mailing list than StackOverflow - "examples of X" questions aren't a great fit for the SO format, usually.

Comment: I guarantee you this question will be rejected because "it can lead to too many answers" while in reality one can be happy to give ANY answer to it. Those "reasons for rejection" are ludicrous. I know there is a need for moderation, but current moderation doesn't make any sense. It stimulates questions with answers "oh, I forgot comma in my code, sorry". The most annoying thing is "OR" style of reasons for closing. Lets say you apply for the job, and you get answer: You are rejected because "you are tall or your uncle maybe drank too much or we didn't like the color of your socks". Go figure.

Comment: Another possibility, although much less probable than "can lead to too many answers" is "this question is not constructive". This obviously means that this question is considered less constructive than, let's say, questions "my code wont compile" and "I can't turn on my computer please help".

Comment: There was a post to the google groups D3 list showing the use of d3 to publish scientific results

Comment: Depends on your definition of scientific data. There're a lot of examples on the D3 webpage, e.g. [political influence](http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/political_influence/index.html?source=d3js) (social sciences) or [gene expressions](http://sulab.org/2013/02/data-chart-plugin-beta/) (biology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the charts found in scientific publications are fairly standard; scatter plots, histograms or line charts are widely used. If you need to create custom charts for specialized purposes, I would recommend [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) and [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Based in the examples mentioned in your question, I guess that you are asking if D3 is a good tool to create *simulations* of physical or chemical processes. I think that simple simulations can be implemented in the browser, although it would probably require to implement solvers for algebraic and differential equations in most cases.

In any case, the [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) gravity and charge attributes are an analogy to the physical gravity and charge, they are not computed in the same way that the real gravity and charge forces, and  thus, the force layout is not suitable for physical simulation.